# How to call the post action of a form from outside it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Hi Guys.  I have a form that will be submitted when a button on my toolbar is clicked. That button is outside the form.  How do I achieve this, below is what I have tried so far. Thanks.

The Button

```
<li>
    <a id="frmsub" title="" data-placement="bottom" data-title="Save" onclick="$('#testfrm').submit()">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-save"></span>
    </a>
</li>
```

My Form

```
<div class="vx-ds-widget">
    <div class="container">
        @using (Html.BeginForm("EditCreateProfile", "Manage", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "testfrm" }))
```

I have also tried this but not is working so far

```
$('#frmsub').click(function () {
    $('#testfrm').submit();
});
```

Comment: that looks ok.. what happens when you click the button?  nothing?

Comment: put this on your console and check what happens `$('#testfrm').submit();`

Comment: Show your ACTUAL HTML, not your .NET server code.

Comment: .NET mangles id names on any controls with `runat="server"`, you need to verify the id name of the form in question is actually what you think it is.

Comment: Aren't we talking about MVC here?  WebForms controls are what get mangled and those aren't used in MVC.  In MVC you simply write HTML in your razor files or use helpers that generate HTML.

Comment: Yes i am using mvc with the razor view engine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#frmsub').click(function () {
            $('#testfrm').submit();
            return false; // to prevent link navigation
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I tried it, but still did not work, when i check my debug console i get this "Empty string passed to getElementById()"

Comment: Does that occur before or after you click your link to submit the form?

Comment: After i click on the link

Comment: Can you tell where the error is coming from, i.e. file, line number, etc.?